# Folder on external, NTFS formated, drive empty after mounty and fstab changes

Tags: mojave, external-disk, ntfs

I have Mojave installed on Mac and an external NTFS formatted hard drive.

a) tried to get writing permission via the terminal
`sudo nano /etc/fstab LABEL=NAME none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse`

b) installed [mounty](https://mounty.app/) and ran it with the same intention

Now folders with big amounts of subfolders and data are suddenly "empty". Some other folders seem fine. I have not done any changes to any of the folders, nor deleted data. File recovery software doesn't show these folders nor the data in them.

I am a bit stressed out, because they contain big amounts of my work and I urgently need the data on Monday.

Thanks for any hint on how to solve the issue.

Comment: *Suddenly all my files disappeared - please help!
This is usually happen when not all files are written properly due to an unmount operation not finishing. The NTFS partition might be marked as "dirty" and the Apple NTFS driver cannot recover from that situation. Mounty will not delete anything by itself, **please try to restore your files on a Windows PC using usual recovery s/w, i.e. chkdsk command line utility or professional tools like GetDataBack for Windows**.* from the [mounty](https://mounty.app/) site.

Comment: Should have put that as an answer :)

Comment: @Karin MacOS doesn't have a driver that allows for writing NTFS so changing the FSTAB to allow it is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @ToddDabney I didn't want to make my comment an answer because I didn't and still don't know what *"File recovery software doesn't show these folders..."* (from Karin's question) really means. File recovery in macOS or Win7/8/10? Karin has to add some details.

Comment: Apple does not enable write on NTFS for a good reason.  If you truly have to have read/write, look at software such as Paragon NTFS.  Meanwhile, you should restore your backup of this important work product to another drive while you work on recovering this one.

Comment: yes, this happens all the time. NTFS write support is a hack on any system except Windows so people sometimes loose files when using any 3rd party solutions(including Paragon or 3G) to write to NTFS volumes on mac. But usually they don't think this will happen until it does. Do not do anything further with the disk. Make a DD clone and work with it to recover what you can. Good luck. i save you post as a warning to those who careless.